# Flutter, iOS native | how to sink on multiple event streams per one FlutterEventChannel?

Tags: swift, flutter, kotlin

I cannot make the iOS native to sink events on two event streams per one channel. However, the Android native is working as expected, i.e. one channel can handle multiple event streams. On iOS native, it seams that only one event stream is possible per event channel? Anyone knows is this intended functionality or a bug in my code?

On Dart side I create one EventChannel and I expect to get stream events from two different event streams.
Here is my dart code:

```dart
static const EventChannel _xxxEventChannel = EventChannel('xxx_event_channel');
...
_xxxEventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream("aaa_stream_of_events").listen((event) {...});
...
_xxxEventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream("bbb_stream_of_events").listen((event) {...});
...
```

At some point on Dart code I start listening both `"aaa_stream_of_events"` and `"bbb_stream_of_events"`. I can see on native side the `onListen` function is called called correctly and `FlutterEventSink` streams are registered. But when ever I `sinkAaaStreamEvents("someData")` also the `"bbb_stream_of_events"` listener is called on Dart side.

Here is roughly my iOS native code:

```swift
public class XxxNativePlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin, FlutterStreamHandler {

    private var sinkAaaStreamEvents: FlutterEventSink?
    private var sinkBbbStreamEvents: FlutterEventSink?

    public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        let instance = XxxNativePlugin()
        let xxxEventChannel = FlutterEventChannel(name: "xxx_event_channel", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
        xxxEventChannel.setStreamHandler(instance)
    }
    
    func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?, eventSink events: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
        if let argument = arguments as? String {
            if (argument == "aaa_stream_of_events") {
                sinkAaaStreamEvents = events
            } else if (argument == "bbb_stream_of_events") {
                sinkBbbStreamEvents = events
            } else {
                // Unknown stream listener registered
            }
        }
    }
    
    func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
        if let argument = arguments as? String {
            if (argument == "aaa_stream_of_events") {
                sinkAaaStreamEvents = nil
            } else if (argument == "bbb_stream_of_events") {
                sinkBbbStreamEvents = nil
            } else {
                // Unknown stream listener unregistered
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

For comparison, on Android native everything is working as expected. i.e. one channel can handle multiple event streams:

```kotlin
class XxxNativePlugin : FlutterPlugin, EventChannel.StreamHandler {   
    private var xxxEventChannel: EventChannel? = null
    private var sinkAaaStreamEvents: EventChannel.EventSink? = null
    private var sinkBbbStreamEvents: EventChannel.EventSink? = null

    override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        xxxEventChannel = EventChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "xxx_event_channel")
        xxxEventChannel?.setStreamHandler(this)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
   
        xxxEventChannel?.setStreamHandler(null)
        xxxEventChannel = null
    }
    
    override fun onListen(arguments: Any?, events: EventChannel.EventSink?) {
        when (val arg = arguments as String) {
           "aaa_stream_of_events" -> {
                sinkAaaStreamEvents = events
            }
            "bbb_stream_of_events" -> {
                sinkBbbStreamEvents = events
            }
            else {
               // Unknown stream listener registered
            }
     }
     
     override fun onCancel(arguments: Any?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCancel arguments " + arguments?.toString())
        when (val arg = arguments as String) {
            "aaa_stream_of_events" -> {
                sinkAaaStreamEvents = null
            }
            "bbb_stream_of_events" -> {
                sinkBbbStreamEvents = null
            }
            else -> {
                // Unknown stream listener unregistered
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You found any solution on this? I think there is no official document for this on flutter

Comment: @Siva my workaround is that I use multiple channels to separate different types of data streams.